# react-native: how to run an app on emulator in offline mode?

Tags: react-native

When I switch my emulator of Android to Airplane Mode, the app i'm developing crashes because it needs the development server.

I'm in need to test offline behaviour for my app, so I ask you how to work offline with an app into the emulator?

GOAL: I must test what the app does when connection is not available. I'm asking if there is a way to test a reac-native app without connection, but without build a production version and installing, because I'm actively developing the off-line mode and I need to re-run the app houndreds of times

Comment: Hmm... I've always turned off my wifi from my laptop, which then sends the signal for `NetInfo` (I'm expecting you're using that) about connectivity change. However it's not fool proof and it may cause false interpretations both on iOS (XCode) and Android (GenyMotion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @zvona mentioned, you can develop offline without wifi connectivity by shutting down wifi *of your computer, not of the emulator*.

If you need to test that your app works in airplane mode, then you'd need to build the app and install the IPA (iOS) / APK (Android) versions.

Comment: If I build the develop version and install, it REQUIRES the development server... I cannot build release version and install it at every test. Really, there is no alternative?

Comment: The dev server is what creates and delivers the updated bundle with each change. How would you expect this to happen otherwise? Maybe you can explain the specific workflow you'd like to achieve. I'm not totally clear on your goal

Comment: I must test what the app does when connection is not available. I'm asking if there is a way to test a reac-native app without connection, but without build a production version and installing, because I'm actively developing the off-line mode and I need to re-run the app houndreds of times! I accept a 'no' as answer... if something is not possible .. amen, it's not possibile. ... I'm just looking for a trick, or a workaround ... if it exists

Comment: When I'm testing offline features, I simply turn off my computer's WiFi, leaving the emulated app's connection to the dev server intact. Since I've already mentioned this, as has zvona, maybe you can enlighten us as to why this won't work in your case

Comment: i've not tried this simple way... sorry... It's a working solution. Thanks, please, add this to your answer for future reference

Comment: But it is there already :-\. If you think it can be written more clearly, you can "suggest edit" it

Comment: Regrettably this is not a working solution. When I build my APK and run on a real device, the offline behavior of firestore getDocs seems to be to return an empty snapshot (very bad, this is the thing I'm trying to debug). When I run the app on a emulator and turn of my PC's internet connect, there is a log in the console (from Expo I think?) saying "Networking has been disabled", and the behavior of firestore getDocs is instead to hang forever. In short it seems that somehow the behavior of an offline phone and an emulator on an offline PC are not the same...

Comment: @StefanTodoran sounds like your issues have more to do with Firestore than anything else. You might want to try wrapping your call to getDocs in a timeout function. I'm not familiar with Firestore specifically, so it might also be worth submitting your case to that community. Good luck!

Comment: @ChrisGeirman Hmm, that doesn't seem right though... why should the firebase code in a React Native app behave differently when running within an emulator which is offline compared to running within a physical device which is offline? Is the whole point of the emulator not to emulate the behavior of the real device? The point being that this solution, while similar, does not exactly mimic the behavior of an offline device. Firebase merely happens to be the library demonstrating this difference, but other network dependent code may exhibit behavior differences too.

Comment: @StefanTodoran you're right, emulators do try to replicate the on-device experience as much as possible. But unfortunately I believe there will always be differences. I don't have any better guesses for you, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

On the Android Virtual Device, click on the three dots -> Cellular and set Data Status to Unregistered (Off):

[image]

Comment: This is not working and the device is still in online.

Answer (score 3):

It is not so straight forward to determine the user is offline and develop Android Apps under this context.

- Having a WiFi available, or Data connection available, is not the same as having Internet. If you toggle them off in your emulator or device, you lose the Metro Server. When you toggle your computer WiFi off, you will lose Internet Connectivity.
- What if the user's signal is extremely poor, both Connection and Internet available, and your app downloads a file that is quite large. You should probably alert the user it can take a long time and ask him whether they would prefer to download later when signal is better for example.
- What if the user has only Mobile Data Connection, no WiFi, and your download could waste all their data allowance?
- How to inform the user about the reason for a problem. "File not download as you are offline"? What does offline means to the user? "No WiFi?", "No data allowance"? "No signal"? "Data connection off"? ...

So I am not using the word offline, instead let's talk about Connectivity. I think to develop a Connectivity aware app properly you must have all the above scenarios in mind. And like you said be able to easily simulate them.

Also you would want to be able to simulate them fast, with little interaction with emulator, device, or WiFi settings. And probably even mock them with some Jest Testing framework. The latter, being out of scope, but good to know about it.

My advice to you would be

1. Implement a ConnectivityProvider that listens to changes in connectivity and shares connectivity state.
2. Make those components who need connectivity awareness consumers of this context, so instances of ConnectivityConsumer.
3. Forge different connectivity states in order to test different scenarios.

Here is how Connectivity State would look:

```
details: {isConnectionExpensive: false, subnet: "255.255.255.255", ipAddress: "xxx.xxx.xx.x", strength: 99, ssid: "AndroidWifi"}
isInternetReachable: true
isConnected: true
type: "wifi"
isWifiEnabled: true
```

All you should need to do for developing purposes is to forge this state to test different scenarios. This means in your ConnectivityProvider could override whatever comes from the connectivity state listener with some hard-coded state.

This means all consumers should then be aware of this state (faked or not). Have them behave differently depending on this state as it suits your needs.

This should speed your development time. Once you are quite happy with your code, build an APK and play with your app in Production Mode. This should be just a verification step, take notes of any issues, go back to development and forge the scenario where they happened.

It helps to have Analytics tracking you connectivity state and exceptions/errors, so you can also relate some state with any issues. But hopefully at this point you should have not found many, because the bulk of the problems and implementation you had already done at this point.

For more info see:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
- https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo
- https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/analytics/reference/analytics

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [React Native Netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo). For testing purposes, you can always return `false` for the `reachabilityTest` and with this, you can simulate the offline mode. Since your whole offline mode logic will be based on this package, you should be able to implement and test your app:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  const netInfo = useNetInfo({
    reachabilityUrl: 'https://clients3.google.com/generate_204',
    reachabilityTest: async (response) => { return false; },
    reachabilityLongTimeout: 60 * 1000, // 60s
    reachabilityShortTimeout: 5 * 1000, // 5s
    reachabilityRequestTimeout: 15 * 1000, // 15s
  });

  // ...
};
```

Once you are done with your tests, you can revert it back to test against your BE base URL, etc.

Comment: This method will not work in all environments. For example, running on a real iPhone may not use the `reachabilityTest` function. From the NetInfo docs about `reachabilityTest`: "Only used on platforms which do not supply internet reachability natively."